# php oop and mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, oop, variables

I am trying to make a function that queries an array, and then I will be able to call the separate values. Here, I think you will understand what I am trying to do. Except I am a complete beginner to this.

```
class Posts{

  var $title;
  var $author;

  public function querySinglePost($value){

    $post = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from posts where id=$value"));  
    $this->title = $post['title'];
    $this->author = $post['author'];

  } 


}
```

How can I assign the array values to variables in the class, and then call them in my normal php script/view? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [mysql_fetch_object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php).
I'd also suggest to make that function static which will just return created object. Like this:

```
class Posts{

  var $title;
  var $author;

  public static function querySinglePost($value){

    return mysql_fetch_object(
       mysql_query("select * from posts where id=$value"),
       __CLASS__);

  } 

}

$post = Posts::querySinglePost($value);
$a = $post->title;
//...
```

Comment: If you're refactoring the whole thing, might as well throw in some error / empty resultset handling. +1 for "getting" what the OP is after (I think)

Comment: I love you Slava... You know that right? This worked perfectly. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the lack of any error handling, wouldn't you just do something like

```
$posts = new Posts;
$posts->querySinglePost(1);
echo $posts->title;
echo $posts->author;
```

Comment: Also, PHP 4 died a long, long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

```
$posts = new Posts();
$posts->querySinglePost($id);

echo "return values: \n";
echo $posts->title . "\n";
echo $posts->author . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Posts{

  public $post = array();

  public function querySinglePost($value){

    // fetch... $results

    $this->post['title']  = $results['title'];
    $this->post['author'] = $results['author'];
    // ...
    return $this->post;
  } 
}

$mySweetPost = new Posts();
print_r($mySweetPost->querySinglePost(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can be bit more organized in this case. Consider this class as a model which will extend a base model class. Instead of directly using `mysql_query`, use a database class and using which u can DO database operations like querying the database. insert into database, etc. set this as the db object in your base model class. As a simple demo

```
class model{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->db = new Database(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
  }
}

class Post extends model{    
public $post;
public function querySinglePost($value){
       $this->post = $this->db->query("select query");
       return $this->post;
    }
}
```

You will be calling like

```
$ObjPost = new Post();
$post = $ObjPost->querySinglePost(1);
```